# How can I add custom keyboard shortcuts in third-party web apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I'm a heavy user of some web apps for work, and would love if there was a way to add custom keyboard shortcuts to common button presses for improving my work flow. For instance pressing, <kbd>ESC</kbd> for closing a javascript window, etc.

Is it possible to implement this type of functionality on external web sites through a Google Chrome plugin, or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=de). IMHO it's the best chrome plugin for managing user scripts (and inject them into third-party websites).

The feature list includes:

- manage and edit all your userscripts
- enable and disable your scripts with 2 clicks
- search scripts from userscripts.org by URL (with TamperFire enabled)
- all GM_* functions including (GM_registerMenuCommand, GM_getResourceText, GM_getResourceURL, GM_notification)
- full unsafeWindow access
- a lot of tags supported by Greasemonkey and Scriptish (like @resource, @require, ...)
- @user-agent tag support to overwrite the useragent string at the pages defined by @include